# How do I use my entered UITextField Value as parameter value for swift function?

Tags: swift

I need to be able to take my `UITextField` value and use it as a `Double` to perform the computation that is in my function; however it isn't returning the correct value. I want to take total dollar amount and multiply it by a percent discount. Here is my code:

```
//Text Fields
    @IBOutlet weak var amountTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var percentDiscountTextField: UITextField!

    func calculateAmount(percentage: Double) -> Double{

        var percentage = (percentDiscountTextField.text as NSString).doubleValue
        return (amountTextField.text as NSString).doubleValue - ((amountTextField.text as NSString).doubleValue *  percentage)/100
    }

    @IBAction func calculatePressed(sender: AnyObject) {

        var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Please Enter a Value", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        if (count(amountTextField.text) == 0){

            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        } else if (count(percentDiscountTextField.text) == 0){

            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        } else {

            var finalPrice: Double = calculateAmount()

        }

    }
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? i mean you haven't mentioned where or what goes wrong...

Comment: also, since you get percentage form text field in the `calculateAmount` function, it does not need the `percentage` parameter..

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused as to why the method `calculateAmount` takes an argument, but when you're calling it you're not suppling an argument?

I'll assume `calculateAmount` isn't supposed to take any arguments, here's how I'd write the method:

```
func calculateAmount() -> Double? {
    let percentageFromTextField = (percentDiscountTextField.text as NSString).doubleValue
    let percentageOff = percentageFromTextField / 100.0

    //  Best to check the user entered a value in the correct range! 
    //  Perhaps you could display a message saying the percentage discount
    //  wasn't in the correct range (if nil is returned)
    if percentageOff < 0 || percentageOff > 1 { return nil }

    let amount = (amountTextField.text as NSString).doubleValue
    return amount * (1 - percentageOff)
}
```

Hope that helps!